# Operator in Dirac notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, notation, linear-algebra

Lets say I have a operator $\textbf{A}$ = $ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 
\end{bmatrix}  $ in a canonical basis {|a⟩ ,|b⟩}.

The operator can be re-written  in Dirac notation as $\textbf{A}$= $|a⟩⟨a| + 2 |a⟩⟨b|  + 3|b⟩⟨a|  + 4 |b⟩⟨b| $, since  any operator can be written as the sum of basis states $\sum_{i,j}^{} c_{ij}  |i⟩⟨j|  $ where $c_{ij}$ are the matrix elements. Does anyone know the derivation of this ? I just applied the formula, but want to know how that is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write
$$
\boldsymbol{A}=\sum_{ij} c_{ij}\vert i\rangle\langle j\vert\, .
$$

Then
\begin{align}
 A_{11}&=1\, ,\\
&=\langle 1\vert A\vert 1 \rangle =\sum_{ij} c_{ij}
\langle 1\vert i\rangle\langle j\vert 1\rangle\, ,
&=c_{11}\, , \\
 A_{12}&=2\, ,\\
&=\langle 1\vert A\vert 2 \rangle =\sum_{ij} c_{ij}
\langle 1\vert i\rangle\langle j\vert 2\rangle\, ,
&=c_{12}\, , 
\end{align}
etc.

Answer (score 2):

This formula derivates from how you write the representation of Operators, so, you begin to the operator equation

$$\hat{A} \vert \psi \rangle = \vert \phi \rangle   $$

$ \vert \psi \rangle$ is a complete set of orthogonal basis, thus, they are expanded

$$\vert \phi \rangle  = \hat{A} \vert \psi \rangle = \hat{A}\sum_i \vert \xi_i\rangle \langle \xi_i \vert   \psi \rangle  $$

Multiply for $ \langle \xi_j \vert$

$$\langle \xi_j \vert \phi \rangle  = \langle \xi_j \vert \hat{A}\sum_i \vert \xi_i\rangle \langle \xi_i \vert   \psi \rangle =  \sum_i \langle \xi_j \vert \hat{A}\vert \xi_i\rangle \langle \xi_i \vert   \psi \rangle  $$

The terms $\langle \xi_j \vert \hat{A}\vert \xi_i\rangle $ are the matrix elements of the operator $\hat{A}$ respect to the basis states $\vert \xi_i \rangle$   and can write as

$$\langle \xi_j \vert \hat{A}\vert \xi_i\rangle = A_{ji}$$

Then 
$$ \phi_j = \sum_i A_{ji} \psi_i $$

This can writes as a matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_1  \\
\phi_2 \\
\phi_3 \\
\vdots \\
\phi_j
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{12} & \ldots & A_{1j} \\
A_{21} & A_{22} & \ldots & A_{2j} \\
A_{31} & A_{32} & \ldots & A_{3j} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
A_{i1} & A_{i2} & \ldots & A_{ij} 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
\psi_1  \\
\psi_2 \\
\psi_3 \\
\vdots \\
\psi_i
\end{bmatrix}
$$